# I want to export my whole code base like a package or something like a module that I can import

Tags: flutter, dart

I created an app for a small group of people. I created a lot of widgets/pages and models. Now another group asked if I could make them the app too. I could create a new project and copy/paste al stuff in there, but more groups want this app, and its a lot of work.

My idea was to create something like a package or export the whole code base to another destination, so that I only need to edit one code base and it changes on all app instances. For the new group I only need to change the API URL and some images which can be changed in pub spec.yaml and main.dart. Do you have a working solution for this?

Comment: mentioned I want to export all pages to

Answer (score 0):

Please read those articles about creating new package:

- Flutter Website: [link](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages)
- Tutorial: [link](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-create-dart-packages-for-flutter/)

Also, Pay attention to what is the supported platforms in you package and test it with each platform. You can also publish it to Pub.Dev if you want. but must be on GitHub first.

Comment: Can I export pages and all types of data ?

Comment: @PhilNue yes you can, Read import and export Keywords to fully understand the concept.